# Cant get array to show in line chart using either JS/KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a ajax call to the database to get date fields, which are basically like this.`["2016-3", "2016-5", "2016-6", "2016-7", "2016-8"]`, When I call them from the db I get them exactly as the way you see in the array, but I cannot get them working on the chart, if I manually type those array it works but if I use an observableArray or just a ordinary js array both do not work. Here is the code for the ajax call being made.

```
  var  arr = [ ]; //normal js array 
    self.DateArray = ko.observableArray(); // knockout js array 
    self.LineChart = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/portfolioDevelopment/' + auth ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
               arr = data.slice();
               self.DateArray(data);
               console.log(self.DateArray());
                console.log(arr);
            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        };
      self.LineChart();
```

Both the console.log shows this.[image]

The line chart is working since the values are manually typed in.

```
this.MasnadsLineChart = {
                    labels: ["2016-3", "2016-5", "2016-6", "2016-7", "2016-8"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "My First dataset",
                            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.1)",
                            strokeColor: "yellow",
                            pointColor: "#ffcc33",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40,80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                        },
                        {
                            label: "My Second dataset",
                            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.1)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            data: [41, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90 ,80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                        }
                    ]
                };
```

I tried writing `labels : self.DateArray()` and even `labels : arr`
both do not work, now I am confused on how to get those values to work on the graph.
this is what the ajax call is bringing back
[image] and here is the link from where I got the chart https://github.com/grofit/knockout.chart

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing `arr` with a new array, but not doing anything with `arr` anywhere.

If you want KO to see the data, you need to put it in the observable array, not an unrelated raw array.

Perhaps:

```
.done(function(data) {
    self.DateArray(data);
})
```

Also:

> I tried writing `labels : self.DateArray()` and even `labels : arr` both do not work

It's a KO library, it's probably expecting an observable array:

```
labels: self.DateArray
```

Comment: @MasnadNihit: I think you were initializing `labels` incorrectly as well, I added to the answer.

Comment: labels: self.DateArray, tried it, dint work. I am really confused

Comment: Hey, No one is trying to help out, do you know any solution, would help me alot :(

Comment: @MasnadNihit: Well, **I** tried to help out. But I haven't used the plugin.

Comment: its very weird that if I do it this way self.DateArray = ko.observableArray(["2016-3", "2016-5", "2016-6", "2016-7", "2016-8"]); but when I push the data from the ajax call which is pretty much the same, it does not work

Comment: @MasnadNihit: a generally good thing to keep in mind is that there is no magic.  Your ajax call may be returning data in a different shape, so `console.log` whatever you're trying to push to `self.DateArray`.  Or maybe the library isn't responding properly to the observable changes, try `self.DateArray.push(["2017-01"])` to see how it works with static data.  Or you could try `self.DateArray = ko.observable([]);` and then instead of pushing, replace the array: `self.DateArray(["2017-01"])`.  These are not solutions, but ideas on how to poke at the magic until it shares its secrets.